# Merge multiple instances of event_params from bigquery api

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf, google-bigquery-storage-api

so i want to pull the data from bigquery using its api, im using /queries endpoint for the same,

the event_params have different keys (page_location, ga_session_id, ga_session_number, engaged_session_event, page_title), and also different values (int_value, string_value, float_value, double_value).
the problem is its coming in different objects, e.g., in one object only int_value is there and no other and, in another record, only string_value is there. now i want to have a single record for a single timestamp such that in one object only i have all 4 event_params.value.
i want the result to have one object that have all the event_params.key and event_params.value sort of groupBy

query i am using:

```json
"query":"SELECT geo.country, event_timestamp, event_params.key, event_params.value.int_value, event_params.value.string_value, event_params.value.float_value, event_params.value.double_value, event_date, event_name FROM [big-query-**************_20231017] where event_name = 'page_view' LIMIT 100"
```

output i am getting:

```json
{
    "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
    "schema": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "geo_country",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "event_timestamp",
                "type": "INTEGER",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "event_params_key",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "event_params_value_int_value",
                "type": "INTEGER",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "event_params_value_string_value",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "event_params_value_float_value",
                "type": "FLOAT",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "event_params_value_double_value",
                "type": "FLOAT",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "event_date",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "event_name",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
        ]
    },
    "jobReference": {
        "projectId": "big-query-projectId",
        "jobId": "jobId",
        "location": "US"
    },
    "totalRows": "1250",
    "pageToken": "pagetoken=",
    "rows": [
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "entrances"
                },
                {
                    "v": "1"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "ignore_referrer"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "true"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "content"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": ":::"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "ga_session_id"
                },
                {
                    "v": "169000080"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "anonymizeIp"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "true"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_title"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "some page title"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_type"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "Legal"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_url"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "https://www..com"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_location"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "https://www..com"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "ga_session_number"
                },
                {
                    "v": "1"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "engaged_session_event"
                },
                {
                    "v": "1"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "form_model"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "ooooo"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": ""
                },
                {
                    "v": "1697612281236905"
                },
                {
                    "v": "session_engaged"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "0"
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "20231017"
                },
                {
                    "v": "page_view"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i tried using group by event_timestamp but its giving error such as: "(L1:8): Expression 'geo.country' is not present in the GROUP BY list"